# Spring boot app cannot connect to RabbitMQ on kubernetes Cluster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I deployed a RabbitMQ server on my kubernetes cluster and i am able to access the management UI from the browser. But my spring boot app cannot connect to port 5672 and i get connection refused error. The same code works , if i replace my application.yml properties from kuberntes host to localhost and run a docker image on my machine.I am not sure what i am doing wrong?

Has anyone tried this kind of setup.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: share your springboot and rabbitmy yaml files. it is required to review the files and identify the root cause

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the dns is named `rabbitmq`. If you want to reach it, then you have to make sure that rabbitmq's deployment has a service attached with the correct ports for exposure. So you would target `http://rabbitmq:5672`.

To make sure this or something alike exists you can debug k8s services. Run `kubectl get services | grep rabbitmq` to make sure the service exists. If it does, then get the service yaml by running 'kubectl get service rabbitmq-service-name -o yaml'. Finally, check `spec.ports[]` for the ports that allow you to connect to the pod. Search for '5672' in `spec.ports[].port` for amqp. In some cases, the port might have been changed. This means `spec.ports[].port` might be 3030 for instance, but `spec.ports[].targetPort` be 5672.

Answer (score 0):

Do you are exposing TCP port of rabbitMQ to outside of cluster?

Maybe only management port has exposed.

If you can connect to management UI, but not on port 5672, maybe indicate that your 5672 port is not exposed outside of cluster.

Obs: if I not understand correctly your question, please let me know.

Good luck